# Civi Rules to send an email

Tags: civirules

I am trying to use Civi Rules to send me an email anytime someone donates over a certain dollar amount. Is thre a way to do this? I tried to add the activity type of send mail, but I keep getting this error message.

**Fatal error**:  Out of memory (allocated 116391936) (tried to allocate 16384 bytes) in **/home/lifelight/www/www/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%40/40D/40D353E1%%fatal.tpl.php** on line **5**

Comment: Do you have the Email API extension installed?  You'll need that to send emails using CiviRules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you should be able to do this by specifying the amount, the period when that occured and then setting an Activity as assigned to you, which should itself then send you the email you require.

The templates_c error is unrelated to CiviRules specifically and suggests you should endeavour to truncate the en_US folder.

EDIT: Adding comment from Jon G that you need to "have the [Email API extension](https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.emailapi) installed ... to send emails using CiviRules"

Comment: Once I installed the API extension I was able to send mail.